# What table in umbraco DB does keep information about page url

Tags: umbraco

What table in umbraco DB does keep information about page url?

For example. I have page home, when i created this page, it got autogen url `/home`

I found `dbo.umbracoRedirectUrl`, but not sure

p.s. uses umbraco 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dbo.umbracoRedirectUrl table stores the url information for Umbraco 9.

[image]